# Image from server not updated Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, picasso

i need to show to user his profile image that i load from google cloud storage, the problem is that when i change the picture an upload it to the server, and i refresh the page i still see the old image.
I tried with the ios version of the app and it instantly refreshed so it's not a problem with the server.

To load the image i use Picasso and i do like this:

```
Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(imageURL).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(profilePhoto);
```

I noticed that when i uninstall the app and then install it again it refresh the image so i guess it's a problem with caching.
Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loading the image try invalidating it:

```
Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).invalidate(imageURL);
Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(imageURL).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(profilePhoto);
```

EDIT: Have you tried:

```
Picasso  
    .with(ProfileActivity.this)
    .load(imageURL)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    .into(profilePhoto);
```

Acutally I think the issue is since you are not using a local image, its using the network to cache it.

If the above doesn't work try this:

```
Picasso  
    .with(ProfileActivity.this)
    .load(imageURL)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(profilePhoto);
```

Comment: Hi @Derek Baxter  thank you it was the networkPolicy, now it work.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to solve this.
I had to add the networkPolicy like this:

```
Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this)
    .load(imageURL)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(profilePhoto);
```

Now it works, thank you all.